# Unexpected identifier while compiling ejs in for loop

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm making a for loop in ejs and get this error:

```
Unexpected identifier while compiling ejs
```

Here's my for loop

```
<ul class="results">
  <% for (int i=0; i<results.length; i++) { %>
     <li><%= results[i] %></li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

express code:

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
const results = []
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index", { results: results })
})
```

Comment: `let` not `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `int` keyword inside for loop condition. `int` keyword doesn't exist in JS.

```
<ul class="results">
  <% for (let i=0; i<results.length; i++) { %> // changed int to let
     <li><%= results[i] %></li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```